# Simple C++ Pointers: How to link a child node to parent node

Tags: c++, pointers

I have a very simple node structure I am using to implement Iterative Deepening DFS.  However, I later run into trouble linking a child node to a parent node.

```
struct Node
{
std::vector<int> config;
int depth;
int action; //0 up 1 down 2 left 3 right
Node * parent;
bool operator<(const Node& rhs) const
{
    return depth < rhs.depth;
}
};
```

Later on in my code I get harsh errors when I try to do something like this:

```
int main()
{
cout << "Welcome to IDDFS 8-puzzle solver.  Now calculating movements... \n";

//Initialize base variables
struct Node initial = {orig_config, 0, 0}; //config, depth, action, parent.
struct Node goal_node;
priority_queue<Node> frontier;
std::vector<Node> visited;
frontier.push(initial);
int Current_Max_Depth = 1;
while(frontier.size()>0)
{
struct Node Next = frontier.top();
frontier.pop();
visited.push_back(Next);
if(Next.depth < Current_Max_Depth)
{
    int pos_of_hole = Find_Position_of_Hole(Next.config);
    if(pos_of_hole==0) 
    {
    std::vector<int> Down_Child = Move_Down(Next.config);
    struct Node Down_Node = {Down_Child,Next.depth+1,1,&Next};
    if(!(std::find(visited.begin(), visited.end(), Down_Child)!=visited.end()))
    {
        if(Goal_Test(Down_Child))
        {
        goal_node = Down_Node;
        break;
        }
        frontier.push(Down_Node);
    }

    std::vector<int> Right_Child = Move_Right(Next.config);
    struct Node Right_Node = {Right_Child,Next.depth+1,3,&Next};
    if(!(std::find(visited.begin(), visited.end(), Right_Child)!=visited.end()))
    {
        if(Goal_Test(Right_Child))
        {
        goal_node = Right_Node;
        break;
        }
        frontier.push(Right_Node);
    }       
    }
}
}
```

All I want to do is link this child node (called Down_Node) to it's parent node (called Next).  BUT how can I do this if Next is not a Node* itself?

It's that pointer to Next that is giving trouble.  I tried &(Next), *Next, etc but couldn't get this to work.  I tried making a Node pointer variable that points to Next, but again I couldn't get this to work.  I'm trying to figure this out but having a lot of trouble.  It's my misunderstanding on pointers in C++ that is leading to my downfall.

Edit:  When I try to use &Next to pass the reference, I get a huge garbled error that I am not understanding.

> In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/algorithm:62,
>                    from iddfs.cpp:8:
>
> /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_algo.h:
>   In function ‘_RandomAccessIterator std::__find(_RandomAccessIterator,
>   _RandomAccessIterator, const _Tp&, std::random_access_iterator_tag) [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator > >, _Tp = std::vector >]’:
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_algo.h:4224:
>   instantiated from ‘_IIter std::find(_IIter, _IIter, const _Tp&) [with
>   _IIter = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator > >, _Tp = std::vector
>
> > ]’ iddfs.cpp:225:   instantiated from here /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_algo.h:174: error: no match for ‘operator==’ in
> >     ‘__first.__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_Iterator,
> >     _Container>::operator* with _Iterator = Node*, _Container = std::vector > == __val’
> >     /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_algo.h:4224:
> >     instantiated from ‘_IIter std::find(_IIter, _IIter, const _Tp&) [with
> >     _IIter = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator > >, _Tp = std::vector
> >     ]’ iddfs.cpp:225:   instantiated from here /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_algo.h:178: error: no match for ‘operator==’ in
> >     ‘__first.__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_Iterator,
> >     _Container>::operator* with _Iterator = Node*, _Container = std::vector > == __val’
> >     /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_algo.h:182: error: no match for ‘operator==’ in
> >     ‘__first.__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_Iterator,
> >     _Container>::operator* with _Iterator = Node*, _Container = std::vector > == __val’
> >     /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_algo.h:186: error: no match for ‘operator==’ in
> >     ‘__first.__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_Iterator,
> >     _Container>::operator* with _Iterator = Node*, _Container = std::vector > == __val’
> >     /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_algo.h:194: error: no match for ‘operator==’ in
> >     ‘__first.__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_Iterator,
> >     _Container>::operator* with _Iterator = Node*, _Container = std::vector > == __val’
> >     /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_algo.h:198: error: no match for ‘operator==’ in
> >     ‘__first.__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_Iterator,
> >     _Container>::operator* with _Iterator = Node*, _Container = std::vector > == __val’
> >     /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_algo.h:202: error: no match for ‘operator==’ in
> >     ‘__first.__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_Iterator,
> >     _Container>::operator* with _Iterator = Node*, _Container = std::vector > == __val’

Does anyone know how to begin analyzing this error?  I am looking for line numbers or other info in it and going from there.

Edit2: Ended up being something completely different.  Template errors in C++ with implementing == for my Node type.  I ended up changing my visited variable to a vector of vector of ints.  It's a hack and a workaround, but it will suit what I need.

Comment: What is `Down_Child`? That will try to initialize `config`, correct?

Comment: `Down_Child` has to be of type `std::vector<int>`. And pass `&Next`.

Comment: Down_Child already exists at that point in the code.  It is simply a vector of ints.

Comment: Here is an example : http://cpp.sh/57qm. Also, I didnt initialize `Next` node.

Comment: When I pass by &Next, I get a huge error.  I will post it above.

Comment: Could you condense this to a single code snippet that compiles independently (apart from any error you want us to fix)?

Comment: I am working on it now.

Comment: Next and Down_Node are formed on the stack, if this code appears inside a function. Due to Next.depth+1, I doubt the design COULD form in global scope as static data, and Down_Child probably prevents that, too. So, do you intend for these objects to evaporate when the function exits?

Comment: Based on the error posted in your updated question, I must ask, are these declarations for Next and Down_Node in global scope (outside a function body)?

Comment: No they are not in global scope, nor are they inside of a function.  They are inside of main.

Comment: I'm still working on it and thinking it through, commenting out sections and seeing if I can track down the error.

Comment: Ok, first....main is a function. So these are inside a function. Second question, do you intend these to be on the stack? BTW, this compiles on VS2015.

Comment: I suppose they do need to remain on the stack since I will need to use them later on in main.  For example, eventually I would like to print out some of the data from each Node.  But, I will not need to use them outside of main.

Comment: `std::find` needs the element type to provide `operator==` so that it knows how to compare them. BTW you don't need to put `struct` every time you create a Node.

Comment: The element type is a vector of ints.  There is no == operator for vectors of ints?  If so, then I suppose I have to write a function to check the entire Vector of Vector of Ints to see if any Vector of Ints inside it has all values equal to the one being checked against.  Not too hard.

Comment: `visited` is `std::vector<Node>`, so it wants to compare `Node` objects.

Comment: Ah, there it is.  You know what, I don't think that was intended.  I should be using vector<int> as each element for visited, not Node.

Comment: Your use of std::find on a vector of nodes requires the == operator implemented within Node.

Comment: Well, my plan is to change visited to a vector<vector<int> > since I don't think it will affect my final implementation much.  It seems often to having to do these hacks and workarounds in C++.  I appreciate the help all, I would upvote if I had rep on this account.

Answer (score 2):

Template errors in C++ are some of the nastiest in all of programming. With that said, you definitely need to pass Next by reference, but the template error is coming from somewhere else. It looks like in this case you need to implement `operator==` for your Node type. The only quick way to decipher that based on the error message is to see that it is complaining about that `no match for 'operator==' in ...`, unfortunately for us mere mortals the rest of that error message is not really useful because the error actually get raised in the bowels of the C++ standard libraries where it actually tries to use `operator==` on the `Node` type, but that a place only the very brave go.

Comment: How would i go about implementing == for my Node struct.  The same way I have done the < operator, I assume?

Comment: @user2055216 That's up to you. Which members must be equal for the Node to be considered equal?

Comment: I appreciate the post and I can't upvote from this account.  But it got me thinking about possible solutions.